# How to create a bibliography in plain TeX?

Tags: bibliographies, plain-tex, knuth

I know that you can use BibTeX using eplain and btxmac.tex but I am looking for a minimalist solution with at little code as possible.
I am almost tempted to do everything by hand (see Appendix B of the TeXbook) but it would certainly lack consistency.

I don't mind using more specific commands such as `citebook`, `citearticle` if it makes the parsing easier.

For example, what Knuth used in Concrete Mathematics?

Comment: This sounds like a job for @wipet.

Comment: "For example, what Knuth used in Concrete Mathematics?" The exact system used is documented in [Typesetting Concrete Mathematics](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf). In general, Knuth is against fully-automated bibliography/index processing, so you probably don't want to use his system unless you really like doing manual work. Depending on how close you want to stay to Plain, [OpTeX](https://texdoc.org/serve/optex/0) has a builtin bibliography processor.

Comment: I can see nothing more minimalist than `btxmac.tex`, which has 932 lines of code, which reduce to 392 when comments are disregarded.

Comment: @MaxChernoff I didn't know about "Typesetting Concrete Mathematics", I will take a look thank you. In fact I don't mind doing manual work

Comment: @egreg `btxmac.tex` in itself is small but `bibtex` and `eplain` aren't AFAIK

Comment: the macros for Concrete are [available](https://ctan.org/pkg/gkpmac); there seems to be a few macros for bibliography, but almost no indication about how to use them.

Comment: @Gaussler I always shudder (or shriek) at the sight of mistaking OpTeX (or Opmac) for Plain.

Answer (score 4):

have you seen paul isambert's  [librarian](https://ctan.org/pkg/librarian/)? It handles `bib` files, but bypasses bafll (bibtex's anonymous forth like language), using TeX macros instead.

Comment: This might suit my needs, I'll have a look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it is not pure Plain TeX, but keeps Plain TeX philosophy. First, there is the `opmac.tex` macro, see `texdoc opmac`. It uses the `librarian.tex` for accessing bibtex files, you don't need to use bibtex nor other external software.

A new generation of `opmac` macros is OpTeX, see `texdoc optex` which does roughly the same in case of bibliography records. It is designed for LuaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I prefer to avoid using third party dependencies (or maybe just one macro package)

Comment: @Laravel First of all, you must specify if you will create the reference lists manually (like by `\bib` macro in opmac) or moreover, you want to connect the reference lists with `\cite` macro used in the document or moreover, you want to read bib files and do extraction data from  them. The first task is very simple and you can inspire or copy-paste \bib macro from opmac.tex file (and simplify it if you don't want to connect bib records with \cite). Other tasks are more complicated, but you can inspire from opmac.tex too.

Comment: @pet Is `\bib` just a pretty `\item`? To answer your question, I don't need `\cite` to be connected to the reference list. I guess the best solution might be to define `\refbook`, `\refarticle`, etc. similar to `\bib`